# How should i use VirtualScreenLeft and VirtualScreenTop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my application i need to know size of all monitors combined space, to adjust size of the window if it goes to big.

I found `VirtualScreenWidth` and `VirtualScreenHeight` in `System.Windows.SystemParameters` and it seems like what i need. But also i wonder what is `VirtualScreenLeft` and `VirtualScreenTop` and how i should take it in consideration? In which scenarios this values are set to not 0?

Comment: is this wpf? or something else?

Comment: I think if your main monitor is on the right, and the monitor on the left or right of that one is positioned above the main monitor, these values can be negative. I believe that the main monitor upper left is always 0,0, everything else is referenced from there. Might want to check on that though but I believe that is the case.

Comment: @RonBeyer you are wrong: 
_The virtual screen is the bounding rectangle of all display monitors_ [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.virtualscreenleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Simon, I'm actually not wrong, I didn't say it wasn't a bounding box, but it **is** referenced to the main monitor. I just tried this on my box, my main monitor is on the left, level gave me (0,0,3840,1080) (x,y,w,h) and when I moved my right monitor up 487 pixels, the value then became (0,-487,3840,1567)

Comment: Well, thank you @Ron Beyer, u can post it as answer i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual screen is the bounding box containing all the monitors of the system. The bounding box is referenced at `0,0` being the upper-left corner of the main monitor (the main-monitor is defined in the system properties).

This means that the bounding box can have negative numbers as the Left/Top values. For example, lets say you have 2 1920x1080 monitors. The main monitor is set to the one on the right (but level at the top), the bounding box will be `-1920,0,3840,1080` (x,y,w,h).

If you move the left monitor up 500 pixels, the bounding box becomes `-1920,-500,3840,1580`. Its important to note that some areas of the bounding box will not be visible to the user, so if you are designing a screen that takes up as much area as both monitors have, be aware that they may not be set up in a rectangular shape. They also may not be both the same resolution.